# make query from Closure table by name from other table in sqlachemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have three tables in my database.

The `Task` table is

| idTask | task | descendant_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1+2+3+4 | 4 |
| 2 | 6+7+8+9 | 4 |

The `Topic` table is

| id_c | name_category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mathematics |
| 2 | Algebra |
| 3 | Progression |
| 4 | Number sequences |

The `ClosureTableCategory` is

| ancestor | descendant | depth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 0 |

In SQL Alchemy the structure is:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

class Task(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'task'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    task = db.Column(db.Text)
    topics = db.relationship('Topic', backref='task')
    topics_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('topic.id'))


class ClosureTableCategory(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ClosureTableCategory'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ancestor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('topic.id'))
    descendant_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('topic.id'))
    depth = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

# ancestor = db.relationship('Topic', foreign_keys=[ancestor_id])
# descendant = db.relationship('Topic', foreign_keys=[descendant_id])


class Topic(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'topic'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(140))
    descendant = db.relationship(
        'Topic',
        backref='ancestors',
        secondary='ClosureTableCategory',
        primaryjoin=id == ClosureTableCategory.ancestor_id,
        secondaryjoin=id == ClosureTableCategory.descendant_id
    )
```

I need to get query from table of task by name. My code is:

```
top   = Topic.query.filter(Topic.name == "Algebra").first()
top_2 = ClosureTableCategory.query.filter(db.or_(ClosureTableCategory.descendant_id == top.id,ClosureTableCategory.ancestor_id==top.id)).all()

top_3 =[]
for topi in top_2:
    top_3.append(topi.ancestor_id)
    top_3.append(topi.descendant_id)

top_4 = Task.query.filter(Task.topics_id.in_(top_3)).all()
for topi in top_4:
    print(str(topi.task))
```

It works, but the code is very big and awful in my point of view. How to make it smaller and more efficient?

Comment: Is "descendant_id" on your info for Task supposed to be "topic_id"? Just trying to clarify to help you out... Also, I'd check the syntax on that descendant relationship in Topic.

Comment: Also, have you tried writing a join? Something like `Task.query.join(ClosureTableCategory, Task.topics_id == ClosureTableCategory.ancestor_id).join(Topic, ClosureTableCategory.descendant_id == Topic.id).filter(Topic.name == 'Algebra').all()`? Obviously update to fulfill all your needs, but this should at least get you started.

Comment: top_5 = Task.query.join(ClosureTableCategory, Task.topics_id == ClosureTableCategory.ancestor_id).join(Topic, ClosureTableCategory.descendant_id == Topic.id).filter(Topic.name == 'Algebra').all()
print(top_5)  #answer is []